# Compare folders and find common files

Tags: c++, winapi

I found this [Powershell command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62246166) useful in comparing folders and find common and different files.
Since I really like C and C++, I've decided to create a program to do that.

It will get all files in 2 folders given as arguments, will store them in an `std::map`.
After, it will compare the 2 maps and give the common files. Is using `std::map` the best container for this?

Some notes:

The `findFiles` method should benefit from RAII treatment, but since I have ZERO work or internship experience, I am unable to implement that.

Some functions like finding a file size and iterating over a folder are present in C++ 17, but I use Digital Mars, an old compiler not up to date.

I use this compiler because it is small, provided as a compressed folder aka portable in the mainstream lexicon (even though portable means something else) and it is straightforward to use.

I used an online code beautifier for indentation.

The `sanitizePath` method is used to eliminate trailing "/" or "\" from the given path.

Please give all your valuable comments on this work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <windows.h>

#ifndef INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
constexpr DWORD INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES = ((DWORD)-1);
#endif

bool IsDir(const std::string &path)
{
    DWORD Attr;

    Attr = GetFileAttributes(path.c_str());
    if (Attr == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    return false;

    return (bool)(Attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
}

std::string sanitizePath(std::string const &input)
{
auto pos = input.find_last_not_of("/\\");
return input.substr(0, pos + 1);
}

std::map<std::string, unsigned long > findFiles(std::string &spath)
{
size_t i = 1;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

std::map<std::string, unsigned long > list;

std::string sourcepath = spath + std::string("\\*.*");

HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(sourcepath.c_str(), &FindFileData);

if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    do {
        std::string fullpath = std::string(spath) + std::string("\\") + std::string(FindFileData.cFileName);

        if (*(fullpath.rbegin()) == '.')
            continue;
        else
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes &FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            findFiles(fullpath);
        else
        {
            list[FindFileData.cFileName] = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh *(MAXWORD + 1) + FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

FindClose(hFind);

return list;
}

void displayMap(std::map<std::string, unsigned long > &map)
{
std::map<std::string, unsigned long>::const_iterator itr;

for (itr = map.begin(); itr != map.end(); itr++)
    std::cout << "File Name: " << itr->first << " Size: " << itr->second << " bytes" << std::endl;
}

std::map<std::string, unsigned long > map_intersect(std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const 
 &source, std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const &dest)
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > inter;
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long>::const_iterator iter = dest.begin();
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long>::const_iterator end = dest.end();
    for (; iter != end; iter++)
    {
        if (source.find(iter->first) != source.end())
        {
        inter[iter->first] = iter->second;
        }
    }

    return inter;
   }

std::map<std::string, unsigned long > map_difference(std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const 
    &source, std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const &dest)
    {
        std::map<std::string, unsigned long > diff = source;
        std::map<std::string, unsigned long>::const_iterator iter = dest.begin();
        std::map<std::string, unsigned long>::const_iterator end = dest.end();
        for (; iter != end; iter++)
        {
            if (source.find(iter->first) != source.end())
            {
            diff.erase(iter->first);
            }
        }

        return diff;
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if (argc <= 2)
{
    std::cerr << "No path or filename provided" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

const char *source = argv[1];
const char *destination = argv[2];

if (!IsDir(source))
{
    std::cerr << "Source path doesn't exist" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if (!IsDir(destination))
{
    std::cerr << "Destination path doesn't exist" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

std::string spath = sanitizePath(source);
std::string dpath = sanitizePath(destination);

std::cout << "Comparing " << spath << " and " << dpath << std::endl;

std::map<std::string, unsigned long > slist, dlist, ilist, diflist;

slist = findFiles(spath);
dlist = findFiles(dpath);

ilist = map_intersect(slist, dlist);
diflist = map_difference(slist, dlist);

if (ilist.empty())
    std::cout << "There is no common files" << std::endl;
else
{
    std::cout << "The common files are" << std::endl;
    displayMap(ilist);
}

if (diflist.empty())
    std::cout << "The 2 folder are the same" << std::endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simplify For Loops by Using Ranged For Loops**
[Ranged for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) have existed in C++ since C++11. A ranged for loop is basically the equivalent of a `foreach` loop in PHP or C#. The functions `displayMap()`, `map_intersect()` and `map_difference()`. Using ranged for loops in these functions removes the need for the header file `iterator`.

Compare the following functions to the ones in the question:

```
void displayMap(std::map<std::string, unsigned long >& map)
{
    for (auto file: map)
    {
        std::cout << "File Name: " << file.first << " Size: " << file.second << " bytes" << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

std::map<std::string, unsigned long > map_intersect(std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const
    & source, std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const& dest)
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > intersections;
    for (auto file : dest)
    {
        if (source.find(file.first) != source.end())
        {
            intersections.insert(std::pair<std::string, unsigned long>(file.first, file.second));
        }
    }

    return intersections;
}

std::map<std::string, unsigned long > map_difference(std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const
    & source, std::map<std::string, unsigned long > const& dest)
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > differences = source;
    for (auto file: dest)
    {
        if (source.find(file.first) != source.end())
        {
            differences.erase(file.first);
        }
    }

    return differences;
}
```

The use and declaration of iterators is not required and simplifies the code.

**Variable Names**
While the variable names are not `a`, `b`, `c` they are abbreviations and make the code less readable. The functions above have replaced some of the variable names as examples.

In `main()` I would also lengthen the variable names of at least the lists:

```
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > sourceFiles, destinationFiles, intersections, differences;
```

**Put Variable Declarations on Separate Lines**
To make code easier to maintain, each map/list should be declared on its own line.

```
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > sourceFiles;
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > destinationFiles;
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > intersections;
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long > differences;
```

This makes adding or deleting variables easier as well as making the code more readable.

**Use std::string Rather than C Style Strings**
Rather than use old style C strings initialize std::strings with `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

```
    std::string source(argv[1]);
    std::string destination(argv[2]);
```

This ensures that the types match in the function calls.